# Sequelize parentModel.AddChild creates record where parentModel as child

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have configured table the many-to-many relationship to itself. This is a table that implements the "interface" - "I can have an overview, reviewable"

```
///HasReviewModel

static associate(models) {
            // define association here
            this.belongsToMany(models.HasReview, {
                through: models.HasReviewHasReview,
                as: 'child',
                foreignKey: 'childId',
                onDelete: 'CASCADE',
                onUpdate: 'CASCADE',
            });
    
            this.belongsToMany(models.HasReview, {
                through: models.HasReviewHasReview,
                as: 'parent',
                foreignKey: 'parentId',
                onDelete: 'CASCADE',
                onUpdate: 'CASCADE',
            });
            
            
            this.hasMany(models.Like, {onDelete: "cascade", onUpdate: "cascade", foreignKey: {allowNull: false}});
        }
```

Further, in the code, I call addChild() to add a record to the link table, where the Novel (post) will have a comment (review).

```
async writeReview(novelId, userId, text) {
        const novel = await db.Novel.findOne({
            where: {id: novelId},
            include: [{model: db.HasReview}]
        });
    
        let transaction;
        try {
            // get transaction
            transaction = await db.sequelize.transaction();
    
            const newReviewInterface = await db.HasReview.create({});
    
            const review = await db.Review.create({
                text: text,
                hasReviewId: newReviewInterface.id,
                userId: userId
            });
    
            //AddChild - novel added like child
            novel.hasReview.addChild(newReviewInterface, {
                through: {status: 'review'}
            });
            
            // AddParent - novel added like child too
            // newReviewInterface.addParent(novel.hasReview, {
            //     through: {status: 'review'}
            // });
            
            if (!review)
                throw new Error(`Не удалось создать комментарий, отмена транзакции`);
            
            // commit
            await transaction.commit();
            
            return review;
```

But for some reason, it works the other way around. Parent and child change places.

Database record:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/dI42m.png

If we call the addParent method, it is inverted again and creates the record I need.
Why? And how to make it work properly? Where did i go wrong?

P.S. The task before me is to make a universal way of commenting on any entity.
Be it a novel, a post, or another comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a problem!
I declared a foreign key in the wrong belongsToMany call.
Below is the correct entry

```
///HasReviewModel

static associate(models) {
            // define association here
            this.belongsToMany(models.HasReview, {
                through: models.HasReviewHasReview,
                as: 'child',
                foreignKey: 'parentId', //HERE
                onDelete: 'CASCADE',
                onUpdate: 'CASCADE',
            });
    
            this.belongsToMany(models.HasReview, {
                through: models.HasReviewHasReview,
                as: 'parent',
                foreignKey: 'childId', //HERE
                onDelete: 'CASCADE',
                onUpdate: 'CASCADE',
            });
```

The foreign key is set for columns from the **dependent**, subordinate table, and points to one of the columns from the **main** table.

We say - join "THIS" table like a **child** and your **foreignKey** will be parentId.
A key in this table that points to an external.